# PHP object orientated insert not working

Tags: php, mysql, oop, pdo

I am trying to insert order details to mysql DB, however it is not working. Below is the class and function

```
class Order extends Database {
    public function insertOrderRef($sessid, $sessionmember, $total) {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO `orders` (order-id, total, member-id, complete) VALUES (:sessid,:total,:sessionmember, '0')";
        $q = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
        $q->execute(array(':sessid'=>$sessid,':total'=>$total,':sessionmember'=>$sessionmember));
    }
}
```

Here is the function call

```
$createorder = new Order;
$createorder->insertOrderRef($sessid, $sessionmember, $total);
```

Where am i going wrong?

Comment: `$this->conn` this is your problem! i think `conn` is in the parent class?!

Comment: What is not working? What is the error? What do the logs say?

Comment: There is no error, conn is the database class connection which works on all other database functionality, just doesnt insert to database

Comment: add error reporting.

Comment: Both your `order-id` and `member-id` columns need to be wrapped in ticks `\`` - Otherwise, SQL is interpreting that as "order MINUS id" etc. *"There is no error"* - You are obviously not checking for errors. This may not fix your entire code, then again it may, yet it is a big part of the problem.

Comment: @Rizier123 the parent constructor will be called if it is not overridden in the child, but this is still bad practice as a new db connection will be created for each child

Comment: There's no error, because you didn't enable exceptions in PDO. By default PDO simply returns boolean false on failure. YOu never bothered checking if the prepare call fails, e.g. `if ($q === false) { die("something dun blown up"); }`

Comment: Add `setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION)` right after the connection is opened. You'll see the error SQL will throw out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you have column names using hyphens, you need to close them into backticks.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `orders` (`order-id`, `total`, `member-id`, `complete`) VALUES (:sessid,:total,:sessionmember, '0')";
```

Comment: *"When you have column names using hyphens, you need to close them into backticks."* - To further this, SQL is interpreting that as "order MINUS id" etc. thinking OP wants to do a math problem. Not to mention `order` being a reserved word, so SQL is complaining about that too; *ever so silently*.